# How to redirect to external URL and collect client data in Meteor

Tags: javascript, redirect, meteor

My goal is to create a link which redirects to an external URL and track client data like OS, Browser etc.

To achieve this, I created two separate routes. One client route which redirects to a template that tracks client data and redirects to the server route.

Here are my routes:

```
Router.route('/:_id', {name: 'url', controller: 'UrlController'});
Router.route('/redirect/:_id', {name: 'urlRedirect', where: 'server'}).get(function () {
    var url = Urls.findOne(this.params._id);
    if (url) {
        this.response.writeHead(302, {
            'Location': url.url
        });
        this.response.end();
    } else {
        this.redirect('/');
    }
});
UrlController = RouteController.extend({
    action: function () {
        this.render('redirect');
    },
    data: function () {
        return Urls.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
});
```

And here is the template:

```
Template.redirect.onRendered(function () {
    var client = new ClientJS(); // Create A New Client Object
    var userAgent = client.getUserAgent(); // Get User Agent String
    console.log(userAgent);
    Router.go('urlRedirect', {_id: this.data._id});
});
```

Now my question is, is it possible to collect client data from the server route (do I need the internal redirection from `:_id` to `/redirect/:_id`)?

If a user has been redirected and he clicks on the browser's 'back' button, he will see the empty `redirect` template. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get header information from the nodejs `request` object in your route. For example, how to get the user-agent string:

```
Router.route('/asd', {where: 'server'}).get(function () {
    var request = this.request;
    var response = this.response;
    var headers = request.headers;
    var userAgent = headers["user-agent"];
    console.log(userAgent);
    response.end();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is this a good approach if I want to save the details in my database? How should I deal with the String `user-agent`, do I need to parse this? I want to save things like Browser, Browser Version, Mobile Device etc.

Comment: Yes you would need to parse it, it should provide enough information about browser, version, mobile device etc (as long as the user has not faked their `user-agent`). There are a bunch of packages that handle the parsing for you. https://github.com/awwx/meteor-useragent is one of the first ones that came up on Google.